# Create NEW database from Snapshot (SQL Server 2005)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, backup, snapshot

I'm using SQL Server 2005. I've created a snapshot of database (RM_DB), I want to create (RM_DB_NEW) from that snapshot. The only option i get when I right-click on my snapshot is "Restore [RM_DB] from this snapshot".

Can I create a NEW database from my snapshot?

#### EDIT

I'm not interested in creating a backup out of the snapshot, this would undermine the whole point. I can back my DB up any time, and restore any other db from it. I'm interested in the ability of doing it all **DIRECTLY FROM A SNAPSHOT**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A snapshot is not the full set of data... it's basically only changed pages.
It is incomplete without the source database.

So, you can't create a database from a snapshot.

[How Database Snapshots Work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187054.aspx)

[Limitations and Requirements of Database Snapshots](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189940.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

create a new database, restore from the snapshot onto the new db. you may have to go into the options tab and ensure "force overwrite" is checked.

Answer (score -3):

Step 1. Create a backup (*.bk file) from your snapshot.
Step 2. Restore RM_DB_NEW from the backup.

Comment: this would defeat the purpose of the snapshot then, i can create a backup straight from my current DB without using a snapshot

Comment: MSSQL does not support snapshot backups